# Cannot access a very specific site from my router

Tags: wireless-networking, traceroute

This is a problem for me because this site is important to me.

It's MY website. And sadly my email is hosted on my site (which I cant access either)

When I try to access my website when connected to my Linksys E3000 router, these days it simply just doesn't go through.

When I ping it, its all `Request Timed Out`, and when I tracert

```
C:\Users\Kyle>tracert blackjaguarstudios.com

Tracing route to blackjaguarstudios.com [199.188.204.228]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CISCO26565 [192.168.1.1]
  2    16 ms    15 ms    11 ms  11.4.64.1
  3    11 ms     9 ms    11 ms  rd1cs-ge1-2-1.ok.shawcable.net [64.59.169.2]
  4    20 ms    21 ms    22 ms  66.163.76.98
  5    37 ms    36 ms    35 ms  rc1nr-tge0-9-2-0.wp.shawcable.net [66.163.77.54]
  6   112 ms    84 ms    85 ms  rc2ch-pos9-0.il.shawcable.net [66.163.76.174]
  7    86 ms    89 ms    90 ms  rc4as-ge12-0-0.vx.shawcable.net [66.163.64.46]
  8    90 ms    84 ms    85 ms  eqix.xe-3-3-0.cr2.iad1.us.nlayer.net [206.223.115.61]
  9    97 ms    97 ms    99 ms  xe-3-3-0.cr1.atl1.us.nlayer.net [69.22.142.105]
 10   128 ms   128 ms   126 ms  ae1-40g.ar1.atl1.us.nlayer.net [69.31.135.130]
 11   101 ms    97 ms    96 ms  as16626.xe-2-0-5-102.ar1.atl1.us.nlayer.net [69.31.135.46]
 12   100 ms    97 ms   197 ms  6509-sc1.abstractdns.com [207.210.114.166]
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.

C:\Users\Kyle>
```

SHAW Cable being my ISP.

Figuring this was all something to do with some setting I made on the router, I reset the thing back to factory defaults.

Nope.

So I'm at a bit of a loss what to do here, as NO device (Computers, Laptops, Tablets, Phones, PS3/ 360, etc) can access my site or its features, so it's not just my computer either. But every other site is just fine.

When I connect to my neighbors router, the site comes up just fine. And shes with SHAW as well.

What should I do?!

Comment: Post a wireshark capture of the moment when you try. http://www.wireshark.org/ Also do you have any other hardware on your network aside from the router?

Comment: I just tried to, but WinPCap wouldn't install, says it's incompatible with my version of windows (win8), and Wireshark needs it on Windows to capture :(

Answer (score 0):

Is your site new ?
just added recently ?
(more than 24h ago)?

If not your ISP could have hocked you up with a bad performing DNS server.
Or in the case your webserver is fresh and new it didn't get the new DNS entry in their DNS server.

Could you try to use google's DNS server as DNS Settings:

> Google DNS servers:
>   DNS 1: 8.8.8.8
>   DNS 2: 8.8.4.4

try to perform some Nslookup aswell if it can resolve to an IP or not
Let me know if it worked ?

Regards

Comment: I checked with google:

Name: blackjaguarstudios.com
Address: 199.188.204.228

Could you try to traceroute it with the IP address: 199.188.204.228
and see if you can reach it